# How can I extend kendo editor widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, extend, kendo-editor

I need to extend kendo ui Editor widget and custom that.
However, there is strange error in toolbar.js

So I extend Editor widget and define init methods.
In init methods, I call init method from parent using by 'call'.
I defined 'tool' options including 'formatting' when initializing Editor instance.

I just extended Editor widget and defined init method like below.

```
let kendo = window.kendo
let Editor = kendo.ui.Editor

let widget = Editor.extend({
  init: function (element, options) {
    Editor.fn.init.call(this, element, options)
  }
})

kendo.ui.plugin(widget)
```

There are some errors in context of init method.
In toolbar.js
kendo.ui.Editor.defaultTools is undefined....

How can I solve this problem?

```
isCustomTool: function(toolName) {
  return !(toolName in kendo.ui.Editor.defaultTools);
},
```

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'formatting' in undefined
    at init.isCustomTool (toolbar.js?a639:509)
    at init.toolGroupFor (toolbar.js?a639:294)
    at init.render (toolbar.js?a639:641)
    at init.bindTo (toolbar.js?a639:322)
    at subclass.init (main.js?d94c:394)
    at new subclass (kendo.core.js?0f57:193)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.eval (kendo.core.js?0f57:3342)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?eedf:367)
    at kendoJQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js?eedf:202)
    at kendoJQuery.fn.init.$.fn.<computed> [as kendoEditor] (kendo.core.js?0f57:3341)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide unique name to you custom widget:

```
let widget = Editor.extend({
    init: function (element, options) {
        ...
     },
     options: {
         name: 'MyEditor',
         ...
     }
})
```

Kendo uses 'name' field to register widgets in common namespace. You defined a widget with an inherited name, so the standard kendo's Editor widget was overwritten.

Comment: The file 'toolbar.js' is in kendo ui js library, that File is not defined by me.

Comment: I wanna extend Kendo Editor Widget like below link.
[Customize and extend Kendo widget](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget)

How can I customize kendo Editor widget...hmmm